# NSURLRequest returns NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost but reachability says the network connection is on

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlrequest, nserror

In my app I'm downloading big video files in a row and sometimes my http request fails and reports that `NSError` code is -1005, which is `NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost`. I check internet connection through `Reachability` class and it says that its current status is not `NotReachable`. What can be a reason for that? What can make a request fail? Any ideas, guys?

Answer (score 3):

You might not like this but I ran into a somewhat-similar situation a few years back ... the fix, at least for me, was to break the files apart into much smaller "chunks."  Essentially, I switched to a streaming scheme versus having to download them in one fell swoop, and life was good again.

Food for thought ...